# How do I bind the F5 key to refresh the Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms

I was having an issue where pressing F5 when an item was highlighted in Object Explorer would launch Debug rather than refreshing the child elements of the object highlighted. I was able to make it so that F5 no longer launches Debug mode, but I am unable to find the command to bind to F5 to have Object Explorer refresh the child elements of the node. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this? I would appreciate any advice that anyone can provide.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out.

The command to bind F5 to is View.Refresh. The area of the software should be "Global".

Alternatively, resetting the keyboard shortcuts to the default worked for me.

Comment: +1: The reset tip worked for me. I'd never altered my shortcuts, so I wasn't aware that they weren't the default.

Comment: Same issue although I have SQL Search and SSMSBoost installed. Could be the reason.